# Reset Counter Jmeter in loop

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Is there a way to reset the counter after i edit the maximum counter with a variable ? For example see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/21067.png

Beanshell Sampler `vars.put("Loop","5");`
Loop 1 Loopcount 5
Loop 2 Loopcount `${Loop}`
Counter with ${Loop} as maximum
Beanshell Sampler with `log.info(vars.get("Counter").toString());`
Beanshell Sampler with `vars.put("Loop","2");`

When i try this the `${Loop}` in the counter module won't edit.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please try to reword it? Try explaining what series you are expecting, and what you're getting instead. Also for the log to make sense, show what is in your beanshell element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im adding a user defined variable Counter with 0. In the loop i add this piece of code:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("Counter")); 
number = number + 1;
vars.put("Counter", String.valueOf(number));
Add the end of the loop i reset the counter with

vars.put("Counter","0");
```

This works for me